# Reference for msbuild itemgroup content

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, csproj

I several times had trouble finding information about valid elements in csproj files (.NET Core). Especially ItemGroup with Content and Include/Exclude/Update/CopyToPublishDirectory attributes.
Also I am interested in "None Include=..." elements.

Is there any offical reference for all this?

At least I could only find a few SO posts.

**Update**

in the meantime I found this upgrade guide (project.json -> csproj) by Nate McMaster which contains a few examples for Content and None but is far from a reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Comment: There is a [documentation work item](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/2642) on sdk-based csproj docs. I've linked back to your question. There isn't a proper single place that collects all that information at the moment, it is spread between visual studio docs and a few GitHub issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had difficulty finding good reference information about this

This list of well known item metadata properties may help
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx

However for include / exclude attributes (as against properties)
try this msdn link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx

At a pinch I have often written a custom task which takes an itemgroup and iterates metadata - though it's worth noting the difference between metadata (such as the Identity property), and attributes such as include exclude, which are fixed, and explained in the second msdn link

Comment: Thanks, actually I have seen these two and they contain some useful information but there is no mention of Update, None and CopyToPublishDirectory.

Comment: None allows you to have essentially no default build action. I often use it for files which are useful to have in the project (documentation from libraries etc), but are not intended to ever be built.